# How to enable query store in SSMS (Sql Server Management Studio) 2017?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-query-store

I have installed SSMS2017, i don't see Query Store page under db level properties.

[image]

I also tried through command line query:

```
alter database <db_name> SET QUERY_STORE = ON;
```

this doesn't seem to be working either.

Could someone please help on how can i enable query store ?

Thanks.

Comment: You installed sql server 2017? Can you check Select @@version

Comment: what kind of response do you get when running the  `ALTER DATABASE` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading SSMS alone won't work, you need both SQL Server 2016+ as well as latest SSMS to support viewing Query Store Options.

```
-- Major Build Version is 13 for SQL 2016 and 14 for SQL 2017
SELECT @@VERSION
```